# Fixed-size floating point types

Tags: c++, c, boost, floating-point

In the `stdint.h` (C99), [boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html), and `cstdint` (C++0x) headers there is, among others, the type `int32_t`.

Are there similar fixed-size floating point types? Something like `float32_t`?

Comment: You need something like that when you have a data structure with a floating-point value and you also want to know exactly what its size is.

Comment: Bears: all I need to know is if Standard C++ or Boost follow IEEE 754 for floating point numbers.
I do not want a size dependent on architecture/OS/compiler.

Comment: @mobrule: If you just need to know what the size is, you use the `sizeof` operator.  A type like this would be useful when an algorithm requires that it be a known specific size.

Comment: @Stephen Canon - yes, for when you want to guarantee what the size is. Say, that an instance of your data structure will fit in 64 bits and can be passed by value to some external library.

Comment: @StephenCanon Consider a cross-platform serialization library. How can `sizeof` be used to solve the issue of consistently marshalling and unmarshalling floating types?

Comment: I think you can go with #if sizeof(...)s to typedef your floatXX_t. But more important for me would be a guarantee that their bits are in IEEE standard. So I'd prefer having ie: float_IEEE754 typedef - useful when exchanging data between different architecture machines.

Comment: Finally, after 13 years, the C++ standard library has an answer (see mine below)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**IEEE 754-compliant fixed-precision floating point numbers were introduced in C++23.**

Here's how to instantiate a 64-bit float:

```cpp
#include <stdfloat>
int main()
{
    std::float64_t f = 0.1f64;
}
```

The implementation proposal can be found [here](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html)

Comment: This feature was introduced in GCC 13

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `std::float64_t` isn't guaranteed to exist. It's only required if the target architecture supports IEEE floating point -- a compiler for an IBM mainframe could decide to support the traditional IBM floating point format.

Answer (score 53):

Nothing like this exists in the C or C++ standards at present.  In fact, there isn't even a guarantee that `float` will be a binary floating-point format at all.

Some compilers guarantee that the `float` type will be the IEEE-754 32 bit binary format.  Some do not.  In reality, `float` is in fact the IEEE-754 `single` type on *most* non-embedded platforms, though the usual caveats about some compilers evaluating expressions in a wider format apply.

There is a working group discussing adding C language bindings for the 2008 revision of IEEE-754, which could consider recommending that such a typedef be added.  If this were added to C, I expect the C++ standard would follow suit... eventually.

Comment: I hope the working group will bind C/C++ to IEEE-754. So if you want portability you can get it more easily, and if you don't need it you can keep using the old platform dependent types.

Comment: Regardless of IEEE-754 or not, it still won't prevent endian portability problems.

Comment: @Pietro: changing the language won't affect your hardware compatibility, it would only preclude some hardware from compliance. How would an IEEE FP guarantee help portability?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It would encourage hardware vendors to provide compliant solutions.  If part a supports standard C without needing soft-float library hacks and part b doesn't, that's a market advantage for part a.

Comment: @Stephen: Speculation. I don't think hardware vendors need any more encouragement about that. It isn't the language committee's job to twist their arm. Hardware can be faster if fewer restrictions are made on it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: (Almost) no one cares about the speed of hardware.  We care about the speed of software running on the hardware.  Software can be faster if the hardware it is running on is held to standards and the software doesn't need to detect and patch up 15 different special cases depending on what platform it is running on.

Comment: @Stephen: The class of programs amenable to C is much broader than the class of programs sensitive to the FP format and environment. If a platform has already decided to be non-754 compliant, it's probably niche enough to fail other standards as well. Whatever value C compliance has stands apart from 754… they are both brand names. But the true value of a C memory model and 754 numerics are that they are practical ways of doing things! Standards shouldn't be treated as brand-names.

Comment: How on Earth would you get *better* portability by preventing your code from compiling on a number of niche architectures?

Either you rely on floats being IEEE, in which case your code will *already* run on every IEEE-compliant implementation and nothing else, or you don't, in which case your code will run on a wider range of systems. If C++ *guaranteed* IEEE compliance, your code wouldn't magically get more portable, you'd just rule out that it could *ever* run on those non-compliant architectures.

Your logic is completely backwards.

Comment: '"In fact, there isn't even a guarantee that float will be a binary floating-point format at all."' -- Couldn't about the same thing be said for `uint32_t` and the like as well, or does is C only compatible with 8-bit-byte-oriented architectures these days?

Comment: @Dolda2000 There is a guarantee that `uint32_t` will be binary.  There is no guarantee that `CHAR_BITS` == 8.

Answer (score 39):

If you want to know whether your `float` is the IEEE 32-bit type, check `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`. It's a compile-time constant, not a function.

If you want to be more bulletproof, also check `std::numeric_limits<float>::digits` to make sure they aren't sneakily using the IEEE standard double-precision for `float`. It should be 24.

When it comes to `long double`, it's more important to check `digits` because there are a couple IEEE formats which it might reasonably be: 128 bits (digits = 113) or 80 bits (digits = 64).

It wouldn't be practical to have `float32_t` as such because you usually want to use floating-point hardware, if available, and not to fall back on a software implementation.

Comment: The `long double` format on OS X (both 32-bit and 64-bit Intel) is exactly the IEEE-754 double extended format stored in little-endian order.  Nothing funky about it at all.  Bytes 0-7 hold the significand field, and bytes 8 and 9 hold the exponent and sign fields.

Comment: @Stephen: that's good news :v) . Does that agree with the numbers I posted?

Comment: Remember that double extended (unlike the other 754 formats) has an explicit leading significand bit, so `5.0L` has a significand of `a000000000000000`.  Its unbiased exponent is +2, and the double extended exponent bias is `3fff`, so the biased exponent for 5.0L is `4001`.  The actual byte pattern when stored in little-endian order is `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 01 40`, and if you view that as two little-endian 64-bit integers, you will see exactly what you observed.

Comment: (*) double extended as implemented by Intel in hardware, that is.  The double extended format isn't actually pinned down the way the other two basic formats of IEEE-754 (1985) are.

Comment: @Stephen: I'm pretty sure that `4001` in little-endian is `01 40 00 00 ...` If nothing else, the least significant byte comes first. I do expect the sequence `a0 01 40` to appear somewhere in the number (if they only performed a rotation) but I don't think you've explained why `a0` and `01 40` are in completely separate halves.

Comment: `01 40` is exactly what I wrote (the bytes above `40` aren't part of the number, so they need not be zero).  Why would `a0` be in the same half as `01 40`? `a0` is the high-order byte of the significand (bits 56:63) and so it should (and does) appear in the seventh byte of the encoding, which is in the low-addressed 64-bit chunk of memory.  I'm also not sure what you mean by "rotation"; no rotation is happening here.

Comment: @Stephen: the encoding is sixteen bytes long, not eight. The sign+exponent are 16 bits so the top byte of the significand should be at 104:111 or little-endian byte 13.

Comment: No.  The Intel double extended type is *ten* bytes long, which is what I've been saying all along.

Comment: @Stephen: Oh, the 80 bit format. That clarifies everything. Then this is all irrelevant because that's completely nonstandard. The only IEEE format larger than 64 bits is 128 bits: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple_precision_floating-point_format . I was confused because `sizeof(long double) == 16`.

Comment: Now I looked at the unused trailing bits. The reported size is 16, the first 10 bytes are used, the next 2 bytes are zeroed out, and the final 4 bytes are left untouched. I suppose that's specified by Intel, and the padding is supposed to make thing easier.

Comment: "The only IEEE format larger than 64 bits is 128 bits" is false.  The Intel 80-bit types satisfies the specification for the IEEE-754 *double extended* type, and is, in fact, an IEEE-754 type.

Comment: Also, Intel specifies only the 10 bytes that comprise the number.  The ABI imposes some alignment requirements when they are passed between functions, and the compiler can do whatever it wants with the padding bits required to satisfy the ABI (including zeroing them, zeroing some of them, or leaving them untouched).

Comment: @Stephen: IEEE 754 defines "single extended" and "double extended" as all types capable of representing a superset of single and double, respectively. It says nothing about 80-bit, and essentially any extension type implemented by an FPU that also supports standard types will fall into that category. See the defect report I just submitted to comp.std.c++ and we might as well continue discussion there.

Answer (score 25):

If you think having typedefs such as float32_t and float64_t are impractical for any reasons, you must be too accustomed to your familiar OS, compiler, that you are unable too look outside your little nest.

There exist hardware which natively runs 32-bit IEEE floating point operations and others that do 64-bit. Sometimes such systems even have to talk to eachother, in which case it is extremely important to know if a double is 32 bit or 64 bit on each platform. If the 32-bit platform were to do excessive calculations on base on the 64-bit values from the other, we may want to cast to the lower precision depending on timing and speed requirements.

I personally feel uncomfortable using floats and doubles unless I know exactly how many bits they are on my platfrom. Even more so if I am to transfer these to another platform over some communications channel.

Comment: "I personally feel uncomfortable using floats and doubles unless I know exactly how many bits they are on my platfrom. Even more so if I am to transfer these to another platform over some communications channel." - You mean you use text file formats? With these there is the disadvantage of the file size: a 32 float needs 4 bytes; these in text form can represent a four digit number only...

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a proposal to add the following types into the language:

```
decimal32
decimal64
decimal128
```

which may one day be accessible through `#include <decimal>`.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3871.html

Comment: Granted, the decimal types are not the IEEE 754 floating-point types.

Comment: WAIT! We need `decimal24` as well to make things such as reading wav files with 24 bit samples easier!