# Storing a 32 bit float in a file portability concerns

Tags: c++, floating-point, portability

If I store a float in a file via this code

```
fwrite((void*)(&v), sizeof(v), 1, f); // v is a float.
```

how often will a program reading the file with this code cause a runtime error because float is 8 bytes instead of 4?

```
float v;
fread((void*)(&v), sizeof(v), 1, f);
return v;
```

Can I always read 4 bytes and cast that to an 8 byte float? Would that be more portable?

Emphasis on different Windows Platforms 64 bit vs 32 bit.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be less worried about the *size* of the float and more worried about the endianness of it. I'd say the vast majority of C++ implementation use IEEE 754 which would mean float is always going to be 32 bits and double 64 bits.

You may wish to just serialize a text representation of the value, or else take particular care to make sure that the byte order is correct.

Comment: i am targeting windows only. i assume windows is always little endian. apart from their phone software.

Comment: My +1, This is the right answer. You may store IEEE floating point as it is the standard, but your application will still have to handle the **Byte-Order**.

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to store data as text rather than raw binary if you reasonably can. This avoids the above problem and a myriad other issues such as:

- endianness
- element sizes
- differing formats for float et al
- padding/alignment
- forward/backward compatibility between different program versions

It also makes the data usable by other programs if needed.

The down-side of course is that text requires more storage, so if you have a lot of data then text may not be an option.

Comment: The down side of storing float as text is that it is a lossy conversion in both directions. In some applications this is unacceptable. (Of course, if you're just talking about storing a hex representation of the bits, all the issues you pointed out are back in play.)

Comment: Good point - typically you would just want to store an appropriate number of significant (decimal) digits but if you need consistency at the bit level then yes your suggestion of using a hex representation is probably the way to go (although it loses a little portability).

Comment: I don't see the benefit of a hex representation over a pure binary one. You still need to deal with everything in your original list. Putting it into hex doesn't change anything. Since OP is dealing with Windows machines, I think it's reasonable to count on IEE-754 being supported at both ends.

Comment: Hex has the advantage of being independent of endianness, and  you don't have the various other binary issues of padding, alignment, etc. You do still have the problem of representation though.

Comment: Perhaps we mean different things by "hex". I was thinking of a hex representation of the bits of some float representation. That has the same endian issues as a simple octet stream.

Comment: @Ted: my interpretation of this is that you would store e.g. 1.0f as "3F800000", i.e. a natural ASCII hex representation which has no endianness assumptions ?

Comment: How does that have no endianness assumptions? It's four bytes worth of data; what order are the bytes in?

Comment: Well it's just IEEE-754 - it's no different than writing e.g. decimal 1000 - the endianness is taken care of transparently when you read or write the data.

Comment: IEEE-754, unfortunately, does not specify endianness. And if it did (and if everyone used it, which they don't), then why not just go with binary and cut the byte count in half? There is no such thing as "natural ASCII hex representation" any more than there is a "natural binary representation."

Comment: IEEE-754 has no notion of "bytes" though, and therefore needs no concept of endianness - a single precision float is just a 32 bit quantity. Are you seriously suggesting that you would express 1.0f in any other way than 3F800000 ? And even if you did, it's just a convention that the program reading/writing the data needs to adopt - it's still independent of endianness.

Comment: Your convention seems to be, "Here's an integer in place-value hex notation. Stuff that into four bytes (in whatever endianness you use) and reinterpret the four bytes as a float in IEEE-754 format." That's not going to work well on systems where the endianness of floats and integers are different (and, yes, there are such beasts). The whole point of endianness is no more than "a convention that the program...needs to adopt." Plus, I still see no difference between your hex proposal and a binary version of the same thing.

Comment: OK - all I am saying is that is easier in general for a program to read the string "3F800000" and convert that to a float, than it is to read the binary equivalent and then having to deal with swapping bytes to cope with endianness.

Answer (score 1):

The size of `float` might change, but `double` does not.  Are you sure it wouldn't be a better idea to use a `double` then for that purpose?  A `double` is always 8 bytes.

Comment: can you provide an example of when float is not 4 bytes? curious myself

Comment: i am using floats to store offsets in a file larger than the int limit (around 4gb). i chose float because my files werent going to get big enough to require double offsets. i dont mind using doubles if they are more reliable.

Comment: @user826228, A float cannot store numbers that large exactly as it actually has a lower precision then a 32-bit int. It has a wider range because it uses an exponent. If you need larger values then 4G then use an 8 byte int often called long long or __int64.

Comment: You do realize that using a float to store an offset larger than 4294967295 means that you won't be able to have certain values as offsets due to precision? (Heck, same applies to many numbers smaller than 0xffffffff.)

Comment: what an oversight thanks. i was actually ignorant to the existence of __int64. i will use that instead.

Comment: @dragonwrenn, @gordy: FWIW, a double is 8 bytes and a float 4 bytes on compilers that use the FPU or SSE in Windows on x86-32 or x86-64, but this is not necessarily true for other platforms, especially not for other processors. The fact that you have never seen floats or doubles that have other sizes does not mean they don't/can't exist. The standards for C and C++ only mention minimum sizes, AFAIK.

Comment: True.  Sucks living without certainty, doesn't it?

Comment: Only a modicum of certainty is required, in life. Otherwise it would be boring.

Comment: *"The size of float might change, but double does not."* - What? Standard reference, please. Of course I know that in practice a `float` is most probably 32-bit and a `double` 64-bit, but a `double` isn't any *more guaranteed* to have that size than a `float` is.

Answer (score 0):

float pretty universal in referring to an IEEE single precision float, regardless if the platform is 32bit or 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows platform, `sizeof(float)` is always 4 bytes irrespective if it is 32-bit or 64-bit process/OS. Don't know about *standard*, but on most platforms, sizeof a float is four bytes.