# Are floats guaranteed to be 4 bytes with CUDA?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I want to use `cudaMemcpy` to create a ones vector (1,...,1) so that I can do things like sum the rows/columns of a matrix or add a vector to a matrix with CUBLAS. The code will be run on different platforms, so

- how can I guarantee that I'm always going to be working with 4-byte floats?
- is there a `sizeof` function for data types on the GPU, or does the device always use the same data type specifications as the host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your second question first, the device always uses the same data type specification as the host compiler.  So you can use `sizeof(...)` on the host to determine relevant sizes.  Many things would be broken if this were not the case.

To answer your first question, then, we need only ask, *amongst the supported host-side compilers for CUDA*, is the `float` representation always 32 bits?  The answer is [yes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#supported-operating-systems).

As an aside, note that this is generally true for most platforms.  Finding a system which has other than 32-bit floats [is difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715545/storing-a-32-bit-float-in-a-file-portability-concerns).  But as far as I know, there is no general C or C++ requirement that float be 32 bits.  Someone else may prove me wrong.