# Has "long double" a single word name?

Tags: c++, long-double

Many new C++ data type names have a single word name,
for example:

- int16_t instead of signed short int
- int64_t instead of signed long long int
- ...

Has "long double" a single word name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed-size floating point types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Comment: It's not exactly duplicate, as @Armin didn't know what exactly are `intXX_t`.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to have a "64 bit floating point type" anyway. You'd need a "48 bits mantissa, 1 bit sign, 15 bits exponent" type to be fully portable. Unlike integers, floating-point types have internal structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `int16_t` doesn't always mean `short` etc. `int16_t` etc are integer types of specified size, while size of `short` etc is unspecified. You don't need such things for floating point types, because their sizes are specified.

Comment: Are you sure, that the sizes of all floating point types are specified by the standard and are not platform specific?

Comment: Oh well, I assumed C++98 requires IEEE754. Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: So, the sizes are not fixed? :)

Comment: Yeah, just float <= double <= long double

Comment: size of short isn't defined, but its minimum range _is_ defined: -32767 to 32767.

Comment: floating point types are not specified, generally double should take 8 bytes, but on my platform it takes 10 bytes!

Answer (score 5):

These are not long/short names. "Names" like `long int`, `short int`, etc. are usual, BUT **platform specific** and do **NOT** have fixed size. For example, `long int` could be 4B or 8B.

While names like `intXX_t` is integer type with **guaranteed fixed** size - `XX` bits.

And no, there's so such thing in the C++ standard for `double`.

For more information about fixed size floating point types: [Fixed-size floating point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. int16_t and others are defined in stdint.h. Nothing such exists for float/double.

BTW, long is a type modifier and double is a datatype.

In C++, You can define your own double class and make it useable by overloading operators.

Shash

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe so, but you can just make your own

```
#define double64_t (long double)
typedef long double double64_t;
```

Comment: Sure, but that's misleading if long double isn't 64 bits.