# Is there a header which defines float32 like int32 and int32_t?

Tags: c

The header file **stdint.h** declares a potpourri of integer types with guaranteed widths, such as int8_t, uint16_t, int64_t, and so on.

Is there a similar header that declares floating-point types such as float16, float32, float64, et cetera?

Comment: Previously asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types  I'm not aware of anything having changed since.

Comment: Definitely missed that one, @Zack, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 8):

No, standard C doesn't provide this.

But, in most implementations, `float` is the IEEE754 single precision type which is 32 bits. Similarly, `double` is the IEEE754 64-bit double precision type.

Implementations are free to provide extensions for this but, since portability seems to be a prime concern (otherwise you wouldn't be that concerned with the `stdint`-like stuff which is, at its core, a way to mitigate porting problems), that's probably off the table.

Comment: I mentioned a "potpourri", but not a "portability". If you wish to extend your answer, by all means do so.

Comment: @Richard, apologies, no, you didn't explicitly mention portability but, since that's the raison d'être of `stdint`, I thought it was safe to assume your meaning. I've updated to clarify but let me know if you have some other reason for needing this and I'll  happily adjust the answer to suit.