# Floating point types with explicit sizes (like integers)

Tags: c++, c++11, types

Are there floating point type definitions in the standard which use the same format as integers?

For instance, we can specify unsigned and signed integers like `uint8_t` and `int8_t` which has the advantage of clearly telling the developer how big the integer will be (8 bits in this case).

Is there a way to do the same thing with floating point numbers?

For example, is there something like `float32_t` and `float64_t` which we can use instead of `float` and `double`?

I am aware that I could declare these myself, (e.g. do a size check check and then define `using float32_t = float` if a `float` is 32 bits). However, I would prefer if there was something in the standard.

Comment: Short answer: No. [basic.fundamental/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.fundamental-12)

Comment: semi-offtopic: `using float32_t = float` ... your `float32_t` will be just as fixed size as `float`, so this `using` brings you nothing but obfuscation

Comment: What I meant is that I would first do a size check, and then define it. The advantage being that code would not compile if, for instance, a 64 bit float doesn't exist on the system.

Comment: This does not make sense. For `uint32_t`, the meaning of each bit unambiguous. Therefore it is sufficient to just specify the number of bits. But floating-point numbers typically have three parts (sign, mantissa, exponent). These could practically occur in every order. Next, you have real things like subnormals and denormals, where the meaning of one bit depends on the value of another. So `float32_t` is meaningless.

Comment: @MSalters If the OP wants to transfer values between platforms, there is still the question of byte ordering for `uint32_t` (and there are more than two choices for that!).

Comment: @MSalters if you only care about size then also for integers you dont care if the sign bit comes first or last. Yes you dont know the format, but you can know the size

Comment: there are lot of duplicates: [Is there a header which defines float32 like int32 and int32_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16492369/995714), [Fixed-width Floating-Point Numbers in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1331821/995714), [C++ declare platform independent 32-bit float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18705192/995714)

Comment: phuclv - good spot.

Comment: @user463035818: Well, there's a reason I wrote about `uint32_t`.

Comment: This older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524737/3545273) gives some details on the rationale. Not flagged as duplicate, because things could have changed. Specifically a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1703.pdf) for those types has been submitted but AFAIK is still not accepted.