# C++ declare platform independent 32-bit float

Tags: c++, qt, types, floating-point

Is there a way to declare 32-bit floating point value in C++ - ensuring that it will always be 32 bits regardless of platform/compiler?

I can do that for integers like that:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t var;  //32 bit unsigned integer
uint64_t var1; //64 bit unsigned integer
```

is there a way to do something like that for floats? As far as I know,

```
float var; //Usually is 32 bit, but NOT GUARANTEED to be 32 bit
```

is implementation specific, and is not necessarily 32 bit.. (Correct me if I am wrong).

I am using qt, so if there is any solution using it I would accept it - I couldn't find anything like quint16 for floats (qreal changes size depending on platform).

Comment: No - some platforms may have decimal floats.

Comment: What are you going to do with a 32 bit binary floating point data type on a platform without support for that?

Comment: So exactly what do you want to have happen if `float` isn't 32-bits? One can of course make a check `if (sizeof(float) != 4 && CHAR_BITS == 8) PANIC("Not 32-bit float!!!");` - but I'm not sure what you expect the compiler to do instead, if there isn't a 32-bit float...

Comment: @MatsPetersson  - I just want to ensure that float is 32 bit, and not 64  or 16 bit.

Comment: So, are you writing code that is likely to run on really obscure hardware? I mean DSP's and large and ancient mainframes? If not, then I'd say ignore the problem...  [I have a feeling that QT won't work well on mainframes anyway, and DSP's tend to be pretty specialized].

Comment: Pointless. Even if you had two floats that are both 32 bits, they still would be incompatible when one has a 23 bits mantissa and the other a 25 bits mantissa. You would need to specify all widths, not just the total.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed-size floating point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using Qt. which is specific to C++, so I'm not sure why the question is tagged C.

As far as I know, on all platforms where Qt is supported, type `float` is 32-bit IEEE.

If somebody decides to port Qt to, say, a Cray vector machine with 64-bit `float`, you're not going to have a 32-bit floating-point type anyway (unless you implement it yourself in software, but I don't see how that would be useful).

There is no `<stdfloat.h>` / `<cstdfloat>` corresponding to `<stdint.h>` / `<cstdint>`. C and C++ provide `float`, `double`, and `long double`, and imposes minimal requirements on them, but doesn't give you a way to ask for a floating-point type of any specific size.

Your best bet is probably to add something like this in `main`, or in some function that's guaranteed to be called during program startup:

```
assert(CHAR_BIT * sizeof (float) == 32);
```

and perhaps `CHAR_BIT == 8` as well if your code implicitly depends on that.

It's unlikely that the `assert` will ever fire -- and if it does, you've got bigger problems.

You might want to reconsider whether you really need a 32-bit floating type. If your code were running on a system with 64-bit `float`, how would that fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: Thanks! Is it certain Qt only runs on 32-bit IEEE? I tagged as C since I use qt but am not limited to it - any solution ensuring float is 32 bit/providing float data type guaranteed to be 32 bit  would be fine, including C. I would like floating point to be 32 bit since I write 32bit since I do some pointer casts/arithmetic relying on the data sizes.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: It's not certain to me, and it's less certain that it will continue to be the case, but it's very likely. Consider not writing code that makes any assumptions about `sizeof (float)`. Otherwise, decide what you want to do if no 32-bit floating-point type is available. Unless you implement 32-bit FP in software (which is likely overkill), you're going to be out of luck -- and an `assert` is just the way to handle that.

Comment: You can have compile time checks too -- C++ defines the macros `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX`, `FLT_MANT_DIG` (`#include <cfloat>`); or in C++11 code you can use a `static_assert(numeric_limits<float>::max() <= ...)` (or min, etc.) (`#include <limits>`).

Comment: And what about a platform where `float` is 32 bits, but with a different format than the one you want? It's difficult to tell just what your requirements are.

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: Some low end ARMs have only `double` 64 bits IEEE hardware. 32 bits FP can be fairly efficiently emulated in 64 bits., but you have issues similar to the x87 80 bits registers.

Answer (score 10):

There isn't such a sized floating point type, but you can always statically assert that the size is 32 bits. Maybe even something as simple as a global char array:

```
#include <climits>

char static_assert_float32[1 - (2 * ((sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT) != 32))];
```

This will fail to compile if `float` is not 32 bits by declaring an array of negative size.

Comment: Or, more simply, static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4, "require 32-bit floats").

Comment: @Adam: Nope, that fails for CHAR_BIT==16.

Comment: @MSalters, if I read you correctly, you are correct. What I wrote is true if a byte is not 8-bits. Since sizeof returns the number of bytes. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AdamBurry: Yes, C++ defines a `byte` as the size of a `char`, which is not necessarily an octet (8 bits). Therefore, `sizeof(char)==1` everywhere by definition. All other sizes are defined relative to this.

Comment: @MSalters, static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4 && CHAR_BIT == 8, "require 32-bit floats") Better?

Comment: @Adam Burry That would preclude `sizeof(float) == 2 && CHAR_BIT == 16` though.

Comment: @MSalters, Have you seen such a system? I suppose if a propose (sizeof * CHAR_BIT) you will argue that static_assert is not portable to older compilers?

Comment: Well, there is the obvious `static_assert(sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT == 32, "require 32 bits floats"` which makes the 32 obvious and the code portable.

Answer (score 4):

Most common implementations of C and C++ will use 32 bit `float` types. If you really need to catch any platforms where that won't be the case you can use the following to throw an error early in the program:

```
#include <limits.h>
if (sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT != 32)
    // error code here
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a way to detect it at compile time, my earlier answer was flawed.

Comment: As far as I know, `sizeof()` cannot be used in a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @MartinR why wouldn't it? it's compile-time anyway :p

Comment: @user9000: Because the preprocessor runs before the source code has even been parsed; the `sizeof` keyword is just an ordinary identifier with no special significance.

Comment: My clang compiler complains: "error: token is not a valid binary operator in a preprocessor subexpression".

Comment: @MartinR I'm sure you're right. I'll update or delete this answer.

Comment: The desired affect can be achieved at compile-time with something like `typedef typename std::enable_if<sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT == 32, float>::type float32;`, although you'd still have to handle the case when `float` is not 32 bits.

Comment: What about std::conditional? using float_type = typename std::conditional<sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT == 32, float, float32>::type; EDIT: Nevermind. We are defining float32, not using it.

Answer (score 3):

On a platfrom that supports IEEE-754 `float` it's going to be 32 bit. On platforms that don't, different width will probably be the least of your problems. Bottom line - use `float` and don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

The Boolean static member constant `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` is true if and only if `float` conforms to the IEC 559/IEEE 754 floating-point standard.  You'll need to `#include` the header `<limits>`.

Note that this alone doesn't tell you whether or not `float` is specifically *32-bit* IEEE floating point, just that it is IEEE floating point -- some implementation without 32-bit floating point hardware might, for example, choose `float` be 64-bit IEEE floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that the sizeof(float) is 32 bits may be sufficient, in general, but insufficient in all cases.

IEEE 758 defines the well known 32-bit *binary32* which is commonly implemented.  But IEEE 758 also defines a 32-bit *decimal32*, which is primarily use for storage and not computation.  There also exists other non-IEEE 758 32-bit floating point implementations, though certainly not as common.

Even if it is known that `float` is 32-bit IEEE 758-2008 *binary32*, the degree which a given environment adheres to its strict definitions (Nan, subnormals, rounding modes) may vary.  This I suspect is the greatest source of subtle variation of 32-float implementations.

Thus the goal of knowing *precisely* the floating point model used, likely to gain insure consistency across platforms, may be very challenging to detect at compile time.