# Understanding a false sharing example

Tags: false-sharing

I am studying false sharing and I have an example on how to avoid it by padding arrays:

[image: code example]

Just making sure I understand correctly, this would only work if we're using 8 byte integers, right? If we're using 4 byte integers, the whole array would be 64 bytes and it wouldn't avoid false sharing.

Comment: sum looks to be a 2d array of doubles, not int. sizeof(double) is at least 8 I believe

Comment: note that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524355/what-is-the-size-of-float-and-double-in-c-and-c says the size of a double isn't guaranteed, but on systems I've worked on doubles were always 8 bytes

Comment: oh, I apparently didn't notice the double. Thanks

Comment: should I just point that out in an answer?

Comment: @RyanStout yes sure