# Size of memory allocated for float in C

Tags: c, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define max_size 100

float array[max_size];
int n,counter;

int main(){
    printf("Enter the size of the array...\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (counter=0; counter<n; counter++){
        printf("%p\t",&array[counter]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I am just experimenting with this C program and I am trying to verify that the size of a float is 8 bytes. But upon running this code with 5 elements in array, I get the address of these elements as following:

```
Enter the size of the array...
5
0x555555755040  0x555555755044  0x555555755048  0x55555575504c  0x555555755050
```

As you can see for the first float number, my system has allocated memory space ...40,41,42,43 which is 4 bits of space if I am not wrong. But the float data type is supposed to have 8 bytes of space for it. I am thinking that the program should have allocated memory space ...40,41,...4F for 2 bytes of space. So

```
...40-...4F //for first 2 bytes
...50-...5F //for second 2 bytes 
...60-...6F //for third 2 bytes 
...70-...7F //for last 2 bytes
```

So the second address would start at ...80. But this is not the result I am obtaining. What am I missing in this process? Thank you for the help !!

Comment: `sizeof (float)` or `sizeof *array` or `sizeof array[0]`

Comment: Almost all environments use IEEE-754 single-precision for `float` and IEEE-754 double-precision for `double`. That's been true for decades. That means `sizeof(float)` is 4 unless you're using a very unusual system.

Comment: `40 - 4F` is 16 bytes. Address are byte-addresses. It looks like you think that an address references one bit. Maybe that's your confusion (other than expecting `sizeof(float)` to be 8.

Comment: @PaulHankin that means each address consists of 8 bits. Similar to assigning a group name to a group of 8 people.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking me a question or telling me how bytes and addresses work. If the former, yes, a byte contains 8 bits (on any system you're likely to use).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was asking actually. 8 bits = 1 byte is assigned a address. Right?

Comment: Yes, each address in memory stores 1 byte. If you have a 4-byte value (for example a `float`) it'll span 4 addresses, for example `0x55551230 - 0x55551233`. (On very uncommon systems you may not have 8 bits in a byte, and float may not be 4 bytes).

Comment: Most systems are byte-addressed, and most systems use 8-bit bytes, so a difference of `4` between addresses means 4 bytes (32 bits).  Also most systems use 4-byte `float`s.  I am not aware of any system that is bit-addressed.  Historically there have been systems that used 9-bit bytes, and some that have been word-addressed systems (16 or more bits per word).  But almost all modern desktops use 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 5):

C standard does not say anything about the storage size of `float` and it has been purposely left out to the implementer.

Maybe on your system and compiler the size is 4. You can check that out by using `sizeof(float)`. See also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25524355/what-is-the-size-of-float-and-double-in-c-and-c).

Comment: This is the correct answer. The size of the different types vary from system to system.

Comment: sizeof(float) returned 4 which means 4 bytes I guess. But still the output doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @G-aura-V probably the reason you're having trouble understanding is in your question "But the float data type is supposed to have 8 bytes of space" is wrong - normally it'll be 4 bytes. If you do size(double) it'll most likely be 8, while C doesn't guarantee it a float is 4 bytes and a double 8 on just about all architectures.