# Serializing qreal to QDataStream

Tags: qt

Is it guaranteed that serialising a qreal to a QDataStream will produce the same output on all platforms? The documentation states:

> typedef qreal
>
> Typedef for double unless Qt is configured with the -qreal float
>   option.

which suggests that qreal could have different sizes on different platforms. If so, what's the best way to serialize floating point values in a platform-independent way (similar to using qint32 rather than int for integer types)?

Comment: I don't think there is any typedef like that. In fact, even double/float are not always the same size (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Comment: As far as I can tell `qreal` will always be either a `float` or `double` and `QDataStream` will always serialize those in [IEEE 754 format](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#operator-lt-lt-11).  However, if one platform has `qreal` as `double` and another has `qreal` as `float` then there can abviously be discrepancies between the serialized and deserialized data.

Comment: @G.M.: More than just 'discrepancies' - there is the potential for overflow if a value serialized with qreal as double on one platform is deserialized as float on another.

Comment: Have you taken a look [`QDataStream`'s floating point precision](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setFloatingPointPrecision)? Since `DoublePrecision` is the default, then a double or a float will have 64-bit precision by default

Comment: @Mike: Yes, I had seen that and wondered about it. It still doesn't eliminate the potential for overflow across different platforms though, so probably best not to allow a qreal to exceed the range of a float, even if it's typedef'd as a double - and even then, as Felix mentioned, there is no guarantee that float has the same range between systems...

Comment: You're in control of what a "platform" is. `QDataStream` is not generally portable between builds of Qt done by random people. As long as you're the one building Qt, you're guaranteed portability.