# How to have a typedef for float that is C90 and MISRA C2012 compliant?

Tags: floating-point, c89, misra

I am writing code for embedded systems that is required to be written in C90 and Misra C 2012 compliant. Therefore, I am not allowed to used the basic C numerical types.

I know that for a 32-bit system the following code is valid.

```
typedef      float float32_t;
typedef      double double64_t;
typedef long double double128_t;
```

But I would like to know if we can write a portable version of if. For C99, we have the macro `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` in the `math.h` which tell us the size of `float`, `double` and `long double`.

I would like to know how we can implements this while it is portable for C90 compliant systems.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types

Comment: The `_t` suffix is reserved by POSIX, so any type you define with that suffix may clash with a future standard POSIX name.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Perhaps to OP doesn't give a damn about POSIX? I surely don't. `_t` was naming convention in C long before POSIX. Using it is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lundin tbh I don't know that the question is asking, but it does point out that something “is not portable”, and I am pointing out one reason it's not. Personally, I have to deal with infinitely more POSIX platforms than platforms that do not map `float` and `double` respectively to IEEE 754 single-precision and double-precision.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. I edited the question, I was in a rush and I was not clear at that time. hi @PascalCuoq, I am developing numerical algorithms for embedded systems (IoT), and also kind of new to the world of standards. I read that POSIX is for portability of OS, which it is not available for (my) embedded world. My only assumption is that the compiler/toolchain is C90 compliant. So I guess POSIX are not relevant for my case. and another question, Can a POSIX platform be compliant while `float` and `double` are not IEEE 754?

Comment: Could the `sizeof` function be of any use to get the size of the `float` and `double` on the current plateform and then define the types accordingly ? But I don't how you could use it in a header.

Answer (score 2):

MISRA C:2012 Directive 4.6 recommends the use of typedefs that denote the size and signedness...

- for C99 it recommends the use of stdint.h
- for C90 you need to roll your own

Note: stdint.h does not define "typedefs that denote the size and signedness" for floating types, although the example suggests you should define them.

Personally, while I understand the rationale for integer types, I don't see the benefit of float32_t/float64_t/float128_t over float/double/etc as the detailed machinations of floating-point are all implementation defined, and hence portability is a matter for the Gods!

[See profile for disclaimer]

Comment: I am writing a numerical algorithm(and several in the near future) that uses a lot of memory that is provided by the client, the working buffer. So we can have a lot of pointers and memory for all matrices and vector and all the nice maths for that. But clients have different microcontrollers, so it make a lot of sense for developing a portable SW because of maintainable reasons. So yes, it is all implementation defined, and I want it to be portable :)