# Are there standard datatypes for floating point numbers with a given amount of bytes?

Tags: opencv, floating-point

I am looking for the floating point version of uint32_t or int64_t or something similar to solve the following problem:

I am trying to work with OpenCV and accessing an element of a matrix of type CV_32F requires a call of the form

`matrix.at<float>(cv::Point(2, 3)) = 17.0`

which implicitly requires that float is a 32-bit datatype.

Comment: What language are you using to call OpenCV?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed-size floating point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types)

Comment: @DanMašek That's a good link thanks! I am specifically trying to figure out what to use to make the mentioned OpenCV call work.

Comment: Use `float`. Given that it's used internally in OpenCV, I'd say it's not very likely an oddball platform with different sized types would be supported by the library.