# Where are the fixed width floating types?

Tags: floating-point, language-lawyer, c99, fixed-width

What are the C standard fixed width floating point types and where are they defined?

**From MISRA-C:2004, Rule 6.3:**
`typedefs` that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic numerical types.

The MISRA-C:2004, Rule 6.3 quotes that ISO (POSIX) typedefs are:

```
typedef          char   char_t;
typedef signed   char   int8_t;
typedef signed   short  int16_t;  
typedef signed   int    int32_t;
typedef signed   long   int64_t;
typedef unsigned char   uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short  uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int    uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long   uint64_t;
typedef          float  float32_t;
typedef          double float64_t;
typedef long     double float128_t;
```

At my company we are using C-99.
*IAR Electronic Workbench, version 8.4*

We are at MISRA-C:2004 because they voted not to upgrade MISRA, which would require create a validation test protocol and running the protocol.

Platform is ARM Cortex M running MicroCOS operating system.

Here are the detailed questions:

1. What are the typedefs for the fixed width floating point types?
2. What include file are they inside (or are they defined as default by the compiler)?

Comment: Searching `cppreference.com` did not show fixed width types when searched for "float32_t".

Comment: For C++ language, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524737/fixed-size-floating-point-types.

Comment: What **exactly** does MISRA-C:2004, Rule 6.3 say? I do not find the text `float64_t` anywhere in the .h files in a macOS SDK, and it is supposed to be POSIX-compliant. Why did you write “ISO (POSIX)”? ISO is an organization; POSIX is a standard. Being compliant with one thing ISO publishes is not the same as being compliant with POSIX.

Comment: Thomas Matthews, what are you trying to achieve with fixed width FP types, aside from _fixed width_?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: They are trying to comply with MISRA-C:2004 rule 6.3.

Comment: [Fixed-width Floating-Point Numbers in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1331821/995714)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was hoping to find out from OP, hence the question was directed to Thomas Matthews.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: It is clear from the question that the MISRA rule is driving this, not some direct programming need for fixed-width types.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The goal is to remove the MISRA warning because of rule 6.3.  The text is copied from our PDF from MISRA.  Unfortunately, the PDF does not allow copying.  The MISRA-C:2004 document shows the table and mentions POSIX as an example.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica:  I guess the goal is to use type names that indicate the width of the variables.  The integer forms we can use from `stdint.h`.  I didn't find any keywords that showed the width of the floating points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C standard fixed width floating point types are not defined**

- C floating point (FP) goals are designed to embrace variations and many implementations.
- MISRA FP goals are to restrict variety.

Fixed size FP types do not result in uniform bit encoding nor other consistent FP properties.  They have limited usefulness in C - hence they are not part of the C standard or library.

---

**Fall-back**

Code could use below and a `_Static_assert` (since C11) or a C99 [substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385694/2410359).

```
typedef      float  float32_t;
typedef      double float64_t;
typedef long double float128_t;

_Static_assert(sizeof(float32_t)*CHAR_BIT == 32, "float 32");
_Static_assert(sizeof(float64_t)*CHAR_BIT == 64, "float 64");
_Static_assert(sizeof(float128_t)*CHAR_BIT == 128, "float 128");
```

---

**Further notes**

Compliant C may not have all 32, 64, 128 bit FP types, thus unable to define all `float32_t, float64_t, float128_t`.

2 different Compliant C implementations may have a 32-bit FP types, but different encoding.  Compare [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) vs. [CCSI](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format) resulting in different range, precision and sub-normal support.

2 different Compliant C implementations may have a 32-bit FP types with the *same* encoding, but different endians, even if their integer endians agree.

[Rule 6.3 (advisory): typedefs that indicate size and signedness should be used in place of the basic numerical types.](http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/468328/misra-c-2004.pdf): that goal "helps to clarify the size of the storage" and not much else.

[Rule 1.5 (advisory): Floating-point implementations should comply with a defined floating-point standard.](http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/468328/misra-c-2004.pdf) is particularly difficult to achieve.  Even if an implementation uses the same FP encoding as [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), C allows the operations enough implementation defined behavior to differ from IEE 754.

Ideally, in C, an implementation that conforms to IEEE 754 defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`.  Yet *proving* and *maintaining* conformity is challenging enough that an implementation may forego defining `__STDC_IEC_559__` as it may only be 99.999% conforming.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the C standard fixed width floating point types and where are they defined?

There are none.

---

A fixed width FP type is likely insufficient for OP's higher level (unstated) goal.

If a fixed width floating point existed, it may only make for a fixed width.  If would *not* certainly make for a fixed range, precision, encoding, etc.

If a fixed width floating point also defined encoding, portability is reduced.  If will to live with that, consider instead a series of `#if` tests for common FP encoding characteristics and simply use `float, double, long double`.

Comment: Update:  I created my own type name (synonym) for floating point:  `typedef double float64_t;` and this resolved the MISRA issue.  So, MISRA wants POD variable type names that indicate the width of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (unofficial source), MISRA-C:2004 rule 6.3 says:

> … For example, the ISO (POSIX) typedefs as shown below are recommended and are used for all basic numerical and character types in this document. For a 32-bit integer machine, these are as follows:…

This is bad phrasing. It does not mean that POSIX or any ISO standard provides these `typedef` declarations. It means the software conforming to MISRA, *i.e.*, the software you are writing, should itself define these `typedef` names and use them.

If that is not the intended meaning of the rule, then the rule is wrong to imply these types are specified by POSIX, because `float64_t` does not appear in the POSIX 2008 specification. (I did not check earlier versions; I am assuming if it appeared in earlier versions, there would at least be mention of it in the POSIX 2008 version.)